# Can i reduce the edit mode animation time on tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there a chance to reduce the default animation time for edit mode on UITableview in iOS/Xamarin?
Currently i am working on Xamarin App, Default animation time for edit mode is fast. So want to reduce that animation time. can we customize animation time?

Comment: Since animation is a simple bool I suspect this isn't possible. But since this is my 'guess' it's not an answer.

From what I understand you're trying to slow the animation down? Or are you trying to speed it up? If the former, I wonder whether it's wise to do so. A nice animation is nice the first time. Ok, the second, and after that any time it takes beyond the bare minimum becomes irritating.

Comment: Yes Frank, what exactly i am doing is while editing reducing the cell height and coming back again increasing the cell height. By that time screen rendering with animation is not looking good. So i am trying to reduce the animation time then how it looks.